# How to filter multiple $_GET values efficiently

Tags: php, json, filter, get

I have 3 $_GET parameters in the url  which I use for filtering json files
Url looks like this

`keyword=test&date_from=2023-06-01&date_to=2023-06-03`

Sometimes a $_GET is empty:

`keyword=test&date_from=&date_to=2023-06-03`

or

`keyword=&date_from=2023-06-01&date_to=`

What I need is filtered json files `$filterdFiles[]` based on the $_GET parameters

```
$customOrders = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/data/custombuild/json/*.json'); // array of all custom build json data 

foreach ($customOrders as $customOrder) {
    $customOrdersObj[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($customOrder), true); // php assoc array 
}

//iterate over the array
// $val['id'] gives me the name of a json file

foreach($customOrdersObj as $key => $val) { 
    if(!empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to)) {
       if($date_val >= $date_from && $date_val <= $date_to) {
          $filterdFiles[] = $val['id']; // filterd by date_from and date_to
       }
    }
    elseif(!empty($date_from) && empty($date_to)) { // filter by date_from only
        if($date_val >= $date_from) {
            $filterdFiles[] = $val['id']; 
        }
    }
    elseif(empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to)) {  // filter by date_to only
        if($date_val <= $date_to) {
            $filterdFiles[] = $val['id']; 
        }
    }
    else { // no date filter at all
        $filterdFiles[] = $val['id']; 
    }
    
    // then I also need to integrate the keyword search in it in all possible date combinations:
    if(in_array($search, $val, true)) {
        $filterdFiles[] = $val['id'];
    }

}
```

How can I do this efficiently? Filtering by date works fine in code above, but it looks like complicated this way. And I have not even integrated the `keyword` search in it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if $date_val comes from $customOrdersObj or somewhere else.
I assume that an unspecified condition means that the condition shouldn't be tested.

This is a possible solution:

```
foreach($customOrdersObj as $key => $val) { 

    // if needed enable the next line
    // $date_val = $val['date_val'];

    $condDateFrom = empty($date_from)  ||  $date_val >= $date_from;
    $condDateTo = empty($date_to)  ||  $date_val <= $date_to;
    $condKwd = empty($search)  || in_array($search, $val, true);
    
    if ($condDateFrom  &&  $condDateTo  &&  $condKwd)
       $filterdFiles[] = $val['id'];
}
```

Each condition is true if the related filter is not specified or if the row satisfies the filter.
If all conditions are true, the row is taken.

Comment: `$date_val = strtotime($val['date']);` This works great! Thnx very much for solution